# Why is React Native FlatList not working on Android but it is for Web?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I am using Expo to build a react native app with AWS for the backend.

I am trying to display a list of friends using FlatList and the AWS data. The list works and is visible on my web browser, but for some reason, it is not displaying on my Android phone. What might the issue be?

**FriendsList.tsx**

```
import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';
import * as React from 'react';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { FlatList, View, ScrollView, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import { listUsers } from '../graphql/queries';
import FriendsListItem from '../components/FriendsListItem';

export default function FriendsList() {

    const [ users, setUsers ] = useState([]);

    useEffect( () => {
        const fetchUsers = async () => {
            try {
                const usersData = await API.graphql(
                    graphqlOperation(
                        listUsers
                    )
                )
                setUsers(usersData.data.listUsers.items);
            } catch (e) {

            }
        }
        fetchUsers();
    },[])

    return (
        <View style={ styles.container }>
            <FlatList
                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                data={users}
                renderItem={({ item }) => <FriendsListItem user={item} />}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

**FriendsListItem.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import { API, graphqlOperation, Auth } from "aws-amplify";

import { User } from './types';

export type FriendsListItemProps = {
    user: User;
}

const FriendsListItem = ( props: FriendsListItemProps ) => {
    const { user } = props;
    return (
           <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
               
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.lefContainer}>
                        <Image source={{ uri: user.imageUri }} style={styles.avatar}/>
                        <View style={styles.midContainer}>
                            <Text style={styles.username}>{user.name}</Text>
                            <Text numberOfLines={2} style={styles.status}>{user.email}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
                
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>  
    );
}

export default FriendsListItem;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
          flexDirection: 'row',
          width: "100%",
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          //height: '100%',
        },
        lefContainer: {
          flexDirection: 'row',
          padding: 16,
        },
        midContainer: {
          justifyContent: 'space-around'
        },
        avatar: {
          width: 60,
          height: 60,
          borderRadius: 50,
          marginRight: 15,
        },
        username: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          fontSize: 16,
        },
        status: {
          fontSize: 16,
          color: 'grey',
        },
});
```

Comment: make item. id to string(). have you tried it?

Comment: I tried it but it did not work. The FlatList is appearing as an empty box. I can change the style of it (like making the background color blue), but none of the items are showing up. It works on the web browser, but not on Android.

Comment: the answer below is your answer when you de structure as an item ```({item})=>``` you should use item, not the user. or ```({item:user})=>()``` do this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code example, in your FriendsListItem component, any time you use your "user" prop, you need to change it. For example, change this:

```js
user.imageUri
```

to this:

```js
user.item.imageUri
```

What you are passing in is an object (e.g. user), which then contains another object (e.g. item), which finally contains your data (e.g. imageUri).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Turns out I am just an idiot. The expo app on my phone was logged into a different account so that's why it wasn't showing any friends for that user.